# Android Navigation Component - Unwanted blinking on screen navigation

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller, android-transitions

I'm using `navigation` component

```
'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
```

I don't understand why when I'm navigating from my `startDestination` to the next `Fragment`
I get a short blinking and I see the previous activity for a couple of millisec.
This doesn't happen when I'm navigating to different fragments.

[image]

This happens with and without the navigation animations.
Tried with no previous `Activity` in stack and it shows the `OS` home screen.

The `navigation.xml` file looks like this:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/barcodeScannerFragment"
    android:name="com.sightplan.sightplanmobile.feature.barcode_scanner.BarcodeScannerFragment"
    android:label="@string/receive_package_barcode_input_view_header_param_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/barcode_scanner_fragment_layout">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/open_receive_package_details"
        app:destination="@id/receivePackageDetailsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_left_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/wait_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/wait_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right_anim" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/receivePackageDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.sightplan.sightplanmobile.packages.receive_package.ReceivePackageDetailsFragment"
    android:label="@string/receive_package_activity_on_create_header_bar_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/receive_package_details_fragment_layout">
.......
```

The `navigation` (full) desgin looks like this:
[image]

And the code for navigating from the `startDestination` to the `Receive Package` screen is here:

```
val action = BarcodeScannerFragmentDirections.openReceivePackageDetails()
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the code that executes the navigation and the nav graph fragment items (with the actions).

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel just updated the question, if you need anything else let me know

Comment: Please try replacing `exitAnim` with `app:exitAnim="@null"`. If it’ll work, it means that there is something wrong with `@anim/wait_anim`

Comment: as I mentioned in the question this happens without animations as well. I removed the whole animations and the problem persisted

Comment: There is a different between removing the animation and putting `@null` animation. Removing the animation will use a default animation (as far as I know at least).

Comment: Also facing same problem, I also remvoed line as u said but still flking

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the `theme` set on my `navigation` Activity inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I had a custom `AppTheme` with `android:windowIsTranslucent` set to `true`.

Removing that solved the issue.